# Android emulator segmentation fault on android studio and terminal

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm getting a segmentation fault from trying to emulate an android phone on my pc

I've tried to install OpenGL packages, java packages, update everything, change folder permission and all that, but nothing works

My android emulator keeps getting a Segmentation fault. I tried to use indirectly on the Android Studio but the emulator crashes after a few seconds. I also tried different versions of Android and the behavior is the same.

```
./emulator -avd pixel_pie -verbose

emulator: Android emulator version 28.0.22.0 (build_id 5194135) (CL:0514023f0a9dfa2f6382c333f2fb30e3a17fd074)
emulator: Found AVD name 'pixel_pie'
emulator: Found AVD target architecture: x86
emulator: argv[0]: './emulator'; program directory: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86/

emulator: Probing for /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
emulator:  Found directory: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86/

emulator: emuDirName: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator'
emulator:  Found directory: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86/

emulator: Probing for /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64: file exists
emulator: try dir /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator
emulator: Trying emulator path '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64'
emulator: Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: Adding library search path: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
emulator: Adding library search path: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/libstdc++'
emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: '/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/lib'
emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib64/qt/plugins
emulator: Setting Qt to use software OpenGL: QT_OPENGL=software
emulator: Overriding pre-existing bad Qt high dpi settings...
emulator: Running :/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "-avd"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "pixel_pie"
emulator: qemu backend: argv[03] = "-verbose"
emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
 /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -avd pixel_pie -verbose
emulator: Android virtual device file at: /home/marcelo/.android/avd/pixel_pie.ini
emulator: virtual device content at /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd
emulator: virtual device config file: /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/config.ini
emulator: using core hw config path: /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: using snapshot lock path: /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/snapshot.lock
emulator: using multi-instance lock path: /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/multiinstance.lock
emulator: Found AVD target API level: 28
emulator: Read property file at /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//build.prop
emulator: No boot.prop property file found.
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: _no_skin
emulator: autoconfig: -skin 1440x2880
emulator: autoconfig: -skindir (null)
emulator: autoconfig: -kernel /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64
emulator: Target arch = 'x86'
emulator: Auto-config: -qemu -cpu qemu32
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel image requires new device naming scheme.
emulator: Auto-detect: Kernel does not support YAFFS2 partitions.
emulator: autoconfig: -ramdisk /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img
emulator: Using initial system image: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//system.img
emulator: Using initial vendor image: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//vendor.img
emulator: autoconfig: -data /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/userdata-qemu.img
emulator: autoconfig: -initdata /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/userdata.img
emulator: autoconfig: -cache /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/cache.img
emulator: autoconfig: -sdcard /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/sdcard.img
emulator: Physical RAM size: 2000MB

emulator: VM heap size 384MB is below hardware specified minimum of 500MB,setting it to that value
emulator: System image is read only
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.0.53
emulator: found magic skin width=1440 height=2880 bpp=16

emulator: CPU Acceleration: working
emulator: CPU Acceleration status: KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:159: Found: 3 adb executables
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:161: Adb: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:161: Adb: /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:161: Adb: /usr/bin/adb
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:180: Path:/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 40
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:180: Path:/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb protocol version: 40
VERBOSE: AdbInterface.cpp:180: Path:/usr/bin/adb protocol version: 36
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:49: Send [000chost:version] to adb daemon.
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:69: ReadResponse: [OKAY]
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:69: ReadResponse: [0004]
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:69: ReadResponse: [0028]
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:115:  Server version: 40
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: _no_skin
emulator: GPU emulation enabled using 'host' mode
emulator: Initializing hardware OpenGLES emulation support
emulator: Found 1 DNS servers: 127.0.0.53
Content of hardware configuration file:
  hw.cpu.arch = x86
  hw.cpu.model = qemu32
  hw.cpu.ncore = 2
  hw.ramSize = 2000
  hw.screen = multi-touch
  hw.mainKeys = false
  hw.trackBall = false
  hw.keyboard = true
  hw.keyboard.lid = false
  hw.keyboard.charmap = qwerty2
  hw.dPad = false
  hw.rotaryInput = false
  hw.gsmModem = true
  hw.gps = true
  hw.battery = true
  hw.accelerometer = true
  hw.gyroscope = true
  hw.audioInput = true
  hw.audioOutput = true
  hw.sdCard = true
  hw.sdCard.path = /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/sdcard.img
  disk.cachePartition = true
  disk.cachePartition.path = /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/cache.img
  disk.cachePartition.size = 66m
  test.quitAfterBootTimeOut = -1
  hw.lcd.width = 1440
  hw.lcd.height = 2880
  hw.lcd.depth = 16
  hw.lcd.density = 560
  hw.lcd.backlight = true
  hw.gpu.enabled = true
  hw.gpu.mode = host
  hw.initialOrientation = Portrait
  hw.camera.back = virtualscene
  hw.camera.front = emulated
  vm.heapSize = 500
  hw.sensors.light = true
  hw.sensors.pressure = true
  hw.sensors.humidity = true
  hw.sensors.proximity = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field = true
  hw.sensors.magnetic_field_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.gyroscope_uncalibrated = true
  hw.sensors.orientation = true
  hw.sensors.temperature = true
  hw.useext4 = true
  hw.arc = false
  hw.arc.autologin = false
  kernel.path = /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64
  kernel.newDeviceNaming = yes
  kernel.supportsYaffs2 = no
  disk.ramdisk.path = /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img
  disk.systemPartition.initPath = /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//system.img
  disk.systemPartition.size = 2562m
  disk.vendorPartition.initPath = /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//vendor.img
  disk.vendorPartition.size = 800m
  disk.dataPartition.path = /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/userdata-qemu.img
  disk.dataPartition.size = 16g
  disk.encryptionKeyPartition.path = /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/encryptionkey.img
  PlayStore.enabled = false
  avd.name = pixel_pie
  fastboot.forceColdBoot = false
.
QEMU options list:
emulator: argv[00] = "/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64"
emulator: argv[01] = "-dns-server"
emulator: argv[02] = "127.0.0.53"
emulator: argv[03] = "-serial"
emulator: argv[04] = "null"
emulator: argv[05] = "-device"
emulator: argv[06] = "goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin"
emulator: argv[07] = "-cpu"
emulator: argv[08] = "android64"
emulator: argv[09] = "-enable-kvm"
emulator: argv[10] = "-smp"
emulator: argv[11] = "cores=2"
emulator: argv[12] = "-m"
emulator: argv[13] = "2000"
emulator: argv[14] = "-lcd-density"
emulator: argv[15] = "560"
emulator: argv[16] = "-object"
emulator: argv[17] = "iothread,id=disk-iothread"
emulator: argv[18] = "-nodefaults"
emulator: argv[19] = "-kernel"
emulator: argv[20] = "/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64"
emulator: argv[21] = "-initrd"
emulator: argv[22] = "/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img"
emulator: argv[23] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[24] = "if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//system.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[25] = "-device"
emulator: argv[26] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[27] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[28] = "if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[29] = "-device"
emulator: argv[30] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[31] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[32] = "if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=2097152"
emulator: argv[33] = "-device"
emulator: argv[34] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[35] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[36] = "if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[37] = "-device"
emulator: argv[38] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[39] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[40] = "if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//vendor.img,read-only"
emulator: argv[41] = "-device"
emulator: argv[42] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[43] = "-drive"
emulator: argv[44] = "if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576"
emulator: argv[45] = "-device"
emulator: argv[46] = "virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify"
emulator: argv[47] = "-netdev"
emulator: argv[48] = "user,id=mynet"
emulator: argv[49] = "-device"
emulator: argv[50] = "virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet"
emulator: argv[51] = "-device"
emulator: argv[52] = "virtio-rng-pci"
emulator: argv[53] = "-show-cursor"
emulator: argv[54] = "-L"
emulator: argv[55] = "/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios"
emulator: argv[56] = "-soundhw"
emulator: argv[57] = "hda"
emulator: argv[58] = "-vga"
emulator: argv[59] = "none"
emulator: argv[60] = "-append"
emulator: argv[61] = "qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR28X0X22X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.opengles.version=196608 qemu.uirenderer=skiagl cma=320M@0-4G qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/init loop.max_part=7 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 5159992 verity 1 PARTUUID=5B7039AE-8279-4E3C-85E7-326BE637903C PARTUUID=5B7039AE-8279-4E3C-85E7-326BE637903C 4096 4096 644999 644999 sha1 474857f995242997d8b124c2f34d2cf580611a0e 33f2331f085fcc5a92358be8d6b49afa1e7a950a 1 ignore_zero_blocks" androidboot.veritymode=enforcing androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange root=/dev/dm-0 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=500m"
emulator: argv[62] = "-android-hw"
emulator: argv[63] = "/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/hardware-qemu.ini"
Concatenated QEMU options:
 /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/qemu/linux-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64 -dns-server 127.0.0.53 -serial null -device goldfish_pstore,addr=0xff018000,size=0x10000,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/data/misc/pstore/pstore.bin -cpu android64 -enable-kvm -smp cores=2 -m 2000 -lcd-density 560 -object iothread,id=disk-iothread -nodefaults -kernel /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//kernel-ranchu-64 -initrd /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//ramdisk.img -drive if=none,index=0,id=system,file=/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//system.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=system,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=1,id=cache,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/cache.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=cache,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=2,id=userdata,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/userdata-qemu.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=2097152 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=userdata,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=3,id=encrypt,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/encryptionkey.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=encrypt,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=4,id=vendor,file=/home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/system-images/android-28/google_apis/x86//vendor.img,read-only -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=vendor,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -drive if=none,index=5,id=sdcard,file=/home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/sdcard.img.qcow2,overlap-check=none,cache=unsafe,l2-cache-size=1048576 -device virtio-blk-pci,drive=sdcard,iothread=disk-iothread,modern-pio-notify -netdev user,id=mynet -device virtio-net-pci,netdev=mynet -device virtio-rng-pci -show-cursor -L /home/marcelo/Android/Sdk/emulator/lib/pc-bios -soundhw hda -vga none -append 'qemu=1 no_timer_check androidboot.hardware=ranchu androidboot.serialno=EMULATOR28X0X22X0 clocksource=pit no-kvmclock android.qemud=1 console=0 android.checkjni=1 qemu.gles=1 qemu.encrypt=1 qemu.opengles.version=196608 qemu.uirenderer=skiagl cma=320M@0-4G qemu.wifi=1 mac80211_hwsim.channels=2 androidboot.android_dt_dir=/sys/bus/platform/devices/ANDR0001:00/properties/android/ skip_initramfs rootwait ro init=/init loop.max_part=7 dm="1 vroot none ro 1,0 5159992 verity 1 PARTUUID=5B7039AE-8279-4E3C-85E7-326BE637903C PARTUUID=5B7039AE-8279-4E3C-85E7-326BE637903C 4096 4096 644999 644999 sha1 474857f995242997d8b124c2f34d2cf580611a0e 33f2331f085fcc5a92358be8d6b49afa1e7a950a 1 ignore_zero_blocks" androidboot.veritymode=enforcing androidboot.verifiedbootstate=orange root=/dev/dm-0 ramoops.mem_address=0xff018000 ramoops.mem_size=0x10000 memmap=0x10000$0xff018000 qemu.dalvik.vm.heapsize=500m' -android-hw /home/marcelo/.android/avd/Pixel_2_XL_API_28.avd/hardware-qemu.ini
emulator: Android qemu version 28.0.22.0 (build_id 5194135) (CL:0514023f0a9dfa2f6382c333f2fb30e3a17fd074)

emulator: Starting QEMU main loop
emulator: registered 'boot-properties' qemud service
emulator: Adding boot property: 'ro.opengles.version' = '196608'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.fake_camera' = 'front'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'dalvik.vm.heapsize' = '500m'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.hw.mainkeys' = '0'
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.sf.lcd_density' = '560'
emulator: goldfish_events.have-dpad: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-trackball: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-camera: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-keyboard: true
emulator: goldfish_events.have-lidswitch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-tabletmode: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-touch: false
emulator: goldfish_events.have-multitouch: true
emulator: control console listening on port 5554, ADB on port 5555
Not using any http proxy
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:49: Send [0012host:emulator:5555] to adb daemon.
emulator: Adding boot property: 'qemu.timezone' = 'America/Sao_Paulo'
emulator: android_hw_fingerprint_init: fingerprint qemud listen service initialized

emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: _no_skin
emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

emulator: No acpi ini file provided, using default

emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: _no_skin
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: _no_skin
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: _no_skin
emulator: Warning: config.ini contains invalid skin.path entry: _no_skin
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:49: Send [0012host:emulator:5555] to adb daemon.
emulator: onGuestSendCommand: [0x60c59a0] Adb connected, start proxing data
VERBOSE: AdbHostServer.cpp:49: Send [0012host:emulator:5555] to adb daemon.
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to clear cache from Android Studio and reboot my PC, afterall.